# Ignore accents in system.windows.forms.TextBox autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I'm using a textbox with the built in autocomplete-mode.

```
        this.textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = listSource;
```

listSource is an AutoCompleteStringCollection with my string-entries.
Some of the values are starting with accent letters like Š or Č.

If I type 'S' I also want to get all items starting with 'Š'.

Is this possible?

Comment: The TextBox's auto-complete is based on the shell's auto-complete functionality (`SHAutoComplete`, etc.), which doesn't seem to support what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are asking is impossible.

However, you could overcome the problem by converting unaccented letters to accented letters, then running the autocomplete on both the accented and unaccented letters. (Or vice versa)

Would be a bit of an awkward workaround but it may work.

Alternatively you could take out all accents from the list, but I would assume that would be unhelpful.

Otherwise - no. You would have to write your own code to perform this function.